# $routerOnActivate called twice in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-component-router

In one page, we have a link on click of which we make a route change.

```
<td>
    <a class="btn" ng-link="['ResourceList', {job_id: vm.job.job_id, resource_id: instance.id}]">See Tasks</a>
</td>
```

And the route is defined as in our app.js:

```
$routeConfig: [
      .....
      .....
      { path: "/app/task-list/:job_id/:resource_id", component: "resourcelist", name: "ResourceList" },
```

Now in the component's `$routerOnActivate` we read the `$routeParams`.

```
vm.$routerOnActivate = function (next, previous) {
    vm.job_id = next.params.job_id;
    vm.resource_id = next.params.resource_id;
    displayList(true);
```

But the `$routerOnActivate` is called twice.

Hence, `displayList()` is called twice. What am I doing wrong?